# Как передать и обработать id

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

есть таблица для ввода

```
 <input id="id[800][0]" class="span1" type="text" name="id[8]" value="8" >
```

вот 800 мне нужно передать как **id** через **ajax**

думаю на стороне **js** можно распарсить `this.id (id[800][0])`

как разобрать запись вида

> id[800][0] ?

да нужно преобразовать строку в массив и взять элементы многомерного массива, или же explode каким нить пройтись

может проще тогда id записывать как elem1_elem2_elem3  и разбить по разделителю?

---

все таки мне кажется что именованоие было неправильным изначально.

ведь если `<input id="11|5">` то

```
    var arr = id.split('|')
    console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

но все равно спасибо

Comment: Вопрос всё еще не очень понятен, что вы ожидаете в результате? какой-то набор данных или число? или строку?

Comment: @Vartlok, выделить нужно число из первых квадратных скобок. Я так понял.

Comment: @Visman по моему заниматься угадыванием не самое лучшее занятие, лучше если человек явно напишет, что он хочет.

Comment: @Vartlok, там ясно написано `вот 800 мне нужно` и `распарсить this.id (id[800][0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте через `regex`

```js
var re = /id\[(\d*)\].*/i;
var str = 'id[800][0]';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // проверьте результат в m[1]
  alert(m[1]);
}
```

**UPD**

Если нужно оба ID

```js
    var re = /id\[(\d*)\]\[(\d*)\].*/;
    var str = 'id[800][0]';
    var m;
    var id1;
    var id2;

    if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
      id1 = m[1];
      id2 = m[2];
    }

    alert(id1);
    alert(id2);
```

Comment: так получу первый элемент. а второй?

Answer (score 2):

Ловкость `split` и ни какого мошенничества для случая если нужно достать подстроку между первых `[` и `]`:

```js
var str = 'id[800][0]';
var str_num = str.split(']')[0].split('[')[1];
alert(str_num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если формат всегда `id[число]..`, то безо всяких регулярных выражений можно просто брать подстроку, пропустив первые три символа и до закрывающей квадратной скобки:

```
var id = 'id[800][0]';
var n = id.substr(3).substr(0, id.substr(3).indexOf(']')); // 800
```

---

**Upd** если вам нунжы все значения, а не только первое, можно и регулярным выражением получить массив:

```
var id = 'id[800][0]'; // тест

// если достаточно строк
var strings = id.match(/\d+/g); // ["800","0"]

// если нужны именно числа
var numbers = id.match(/\d+/g).map(function(s){return +s;}); // [800,0]
```

Comment: как понимаю вы завязались на длину числа?

Comment: на длину начала строки: "id["

Comment: @des1roer я смотрю, вам нужны все числа, а не только первое. Обновил ответ.